# Javascript + Ajax + Django - chat application issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, django

So i have this application in django+javascript+ajax

```
var friends = "{{friend}}";
function LoadJson(){ //start function
    $.getJSON( "/messages/message/friend="+friends, function( data ) {
        var items = [];
        var lastitem = parseInt($("#showdata div:last-child").attr("id"));
    if (lastitem !== lastitem) {
        var lastitem = 0;
    }
    $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
```

I want to add this here, to read the message and if is larger than 30 and if it doesn t contain no space , it will add every 30 letters a space :

```
        if ( key > lastitem ) {
            var str = val.msg;
            var search = str.search(" ")
            if (str > 30) {
                if ( (search == -1) || (search > 30) ) {
                    newVal = str.replace(/(.{30})/g, "$1\n");
                    console.log(newVal)
                }
            }
```

But everytime i add something to the base application , the application crashes and displays the last message many times.

```
        if ( key > lastitem ) {
            $("#showdata").append("<div class='well well-lg lighter row col-md-12' id='" + key + "'>"+"<span class='pull-left'><span class='sender col-md-3'>"+val.user+"</span>" + "<span class='message col-md-6' style='margin-left:30px;'>" + val.msg + "</span></span></br><small class='pull-right col-md-3'>"+ val.time + "</small></div>");
            $('#bottom').scrollTop($('#bottom').prop("scrollHeight"));
            $(window).scrollTop($(document).height());
        };
    });
});
setTimeout(LoadJson, 5000);
```

};

I will really apreciate any kind of help.
Thank you!

Comment: What about `if(str.length > 30)`?

Comment: When it crashes, what the error messages (or callstacks) say?

Comment: i just temporary solved the problem . thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This just temporary solved my problem:

```
var friends = "{{friend}}";
function LoadJson(){ //start function
$.getJSON( "/messages/message/friend="+friends, function( data ) {
    var items = [];
    var lastitem = parseInt($("#showdata div:last-child").attr("id"));
    if (lastitem !== lastitem) {
        var lastitem = 0;
    }
    $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
        if (val.msg) {
            var str = val.msg;
            var search = str.search(" ")
        }
        if ( key > lastitem ) {
            if ( (search == -1) || (search > 30) ) {
                newVal = str.replace(/(.{30})/g, "$1\n");
                $("#showdata").append("<div class='well well-lg lighter row col-md-12' id='" + key + "'>"+"<span class='pull-left'><span class='sender col-md-3'>"+val.user+"</span>" + "<span class='message col-md-6' style='margin-left:30px;'>" + newVal + "</span></span></br><small class='pull-right col-md-3'>"+ val.time + "</small></div>");
            }
            else {
                $("#showdata").append("<div class='well well-lg lighter row col-md-12' id='" + key + "'>"+"<span class='pull-left'><span class='sender col-md-3'>"+val.user+"</span>" + "<span class='message col-md-6' style='margin-left:30px;'>" + val.msg + "</span></span></br><small class='pull-right col-md-3'>"+ val.time + "</small></div>");
            }
            $('#bottom').scrollTop($('#bottom').prop("scrollHeight"));
            $(window).scrollTop($(document).height());
        };
    });
});
setTimeout(LoadJson, 5000);
```

};